# Gitlab is not sending mails but postfix works, omnibus installation (16.04) how to troubleshoot?

Tags: server, email, postfix, git, gitlab

I used the gitlab omnibus installtion for my 16.04 Ubuntu Server, since I run into dependency issues when `using apt-get install git`. So I ran `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:check` to check my environment.
The check complained that the repo path is not owned by `git:git` which I don't get... the repo path is owned by `git:git` and I can create repos.
So in general everything works as it should be, but mails are not send out.
When running the installation I was asked about my domain and I used my domain without the ending `.de`. May this cause issues? 
So in case I want to change anything I have to change it in the `gitlab.rb` and run a `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, correct?
I tested my postfix installtion and it can send out mails manually...
Port 25 is open.
Any Ideas? There is no test mail function in gitlab, or?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to update your email address with the command `git config`.   Use the command `man git-config` for details.

Check the mail logs for details what is happening with your email.  This is likely `/var/log/mail.log`.  The command `mailq` should list any email messages that has been accepted for delivery, but not yet delivered.

Comment: My email is correctly setup, I mean the one of my gitlab user. The sender I might got wrong since it doesn't have to full domain. "sender@mydomain" and the ".de" is missing probabaly, since I didn't specify this during the installation.

Comment: @Private Submission fixups should fix the domain.  This would be reflected in the mail log.  If it isn't fixed up, that should also be reflected in the mail log.